# How can I implement a \futurelet that ignores spaces?

Tags: tex-core, token-lists

This is a question about token processing in TeX. What am I doing wrong when implementing `\FutureLetNoSpace`?

The book *TEX in Practice: Volume III: Tokens, Macros*, by Stephan v. Bechtolsheim, really does a good job explaining TeX in detail. However, I ran into a stumbling block that I cannot solve using `\tracingall` alone.

Could someone demonstrate how I might use the code from the book.  I also thought `\FutureLetNoSpace` is the user-level/document-level command. It seems to imitate `\futurelet`.

## Code

Here I write the text "Hello there!", and inject my token checker immediately after the "t". It checks for the token "h". If found, it should yield a nice log message and "TRUE" in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex

%\tracingall % all hell breaks loose

\catcode`@=11 % or \makeatletter to change category code of @ to 11 and temporarily to access kernel macro \@tabularcr

\long\def\DoLongFutureLet #1#2#3#4{%
  \def\@FutureLetDecide{% hangs here
    #1#2\@FutureLetToken% becomes \ifx#2\@FutureLetToken, which compares two expanded tokens
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#3}%
    \else
      \def\@FutureLetNext{#4}%
    \fi% the \@FutureLetNext gets grabbed into \futurelet below
    \@FutureLetNext
  }%
    \futurelet\@FutureLetToken\@FutureLetDecide
}

\def\DoFutureLet #1#2#3#4{%
  \DoLongFutureLet{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
} % identical to \DoLongFutureLet

\def\FutureLetNoSpace #1#2{%
  \def\@FutureLetNoSpaceA{#1}% save arg
  \def\@FutureLetNoSpaceB{#2}% save arg
  \@FutureLetOne
}

\def\@FutureLetOne{%
  \DoFutureLet{\ifx}{ }%
    {\@FutureLetThree}{\@FutureLetOk}% \@FutureLetThree if it is a space token.
}

\edef\@FutureLetNoSpaceTemp{%
  \def\noexpand\@FutureLetThree\space{\noexpand\@FutureLetOne}% force expansion of space into a space token and recall \@FutureLetOne
}
\@FutureLetNoSpaceTemp% why are we calling this macro here?

\def\@FutureLetOk{% called when no space is found
  \expandafter\futurelet\@FutureLetTokenA\@FutureLetTokenB
}

\long\def\DoLongFutureLetNoSpace #1#2#3#4{%
  \def\@FutureLetDecideNoSpace{% \@FutureLetTokenNoSpace is self-contained by this macro
    #1#2\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace% becomes \ifx#2\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace, which compares two expanded tokens
      \def\@FutureLetNextNoSpace{#3}%
    \else
      \def\@FutureLetNextNoSpace{#4}% whatever should get executed on match
     \fi
     \@FutureLetNextNoSpace
    }
    \FutureLetNoSpace{\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace}%
      {\@FutureLetDecideNoSpace}% call \@FutureLetDecideNoSpace instead of \futurelet
}
\def\DoFutureLetNoSpace #1#2#3#4{%
  \DoLongFutureLetNoSpace{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\catcode`@=12 % or \makeatother to restore category code of @ to 12

\begin{document}
Hello t\DoFutureLetNoSpace{\ifx}{h}{\typeout{\noexpand\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace value: \meaning\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace}}TRUE}{\typeout{\noexpand\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace value: \meaning\@FutureLetTokenNoSpace}FALSE}here!
\end{document}
```

### Trace

The last four lines of the trace in the console:

```
\DoFutureLet #1#2#3#4->\DoLongFutureLet {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}
#1<-\ifx
#2<-
#3<-\@FutureLetThree
```

Comment: "futurelet that ignores spaces" is more or less the definition of latex's `\@ifnextchar`

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle says, plus see _The TeXbook_, p. 376.

Comment: @GuM So awesome. Thanks! It is not the same implementation as in TEX in Practice, but useful. It uses `\afterassignment` like  in Manuel's answer.

Comment: What's the problem with `\afterassignment`? It's more secure to do `\def\foo{\afterassignment\nextstep\let\gobble= }` than `\expandafter\def\expandafter\foo\space{\nextstep}`.

Comment: @Manuel I have no problem with it. As I said the comments to your answer, it seems more elegant. I am just trying to grasp the code from the book. I thought I understood its recursive calls, but it keeps choking. Safer is better, of course!

Comment: Seeing the code, it seems like overcomplicating things, and I don't see the problem at first sight, In any case you can use `Hello t\@ifnextchar{h}{TRUE}{FALSE}here!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\def\futureletignorespaces#1#2{\def\nextaction{#2}%
  \def\checkspace{\ifx\nexttoken\@sptoken
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\afterassignment\futureletagain\let\nexttoken= }
   {\futurelet#1\nextaction}}%
  \futurelet\nexttoken\checkspace}
\def\futureletagain{\futurelet\nexttoken\checkspace}
\makeatother
```

This started as just a substitute for `\futurelet\nexttoken\action` ignoring spaces `\futureletignorespaces\nexttoken\action`. But I changed the code a bit so that it lets you define the second argument on the fly:

```
\futureletignorespaces\nexttoken\action % or you could define \action in the argument
\futureletignorespaces\nexttoken{\ifx\nexttoken!yes\fi}
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet.

Comment: +1 for effort haha. I am well aware that my question is a pain.

Comment: It does work now.

Comment: Note that this has the same syntax as `\futurelet`. `\futurelet\nexttoken\action` or `\futureletignorespaces\nexttoken\action`.

Comment: Then why switch to `\afterassignment`?  I seem to remember one of them puts a token back into the token stream.

Comment: There's no “switch”: if the next token is a space token, remove it and call again `\ftureletignorespaces`. If there are three space tokens it would gobble all before checking what's next (if for some reason you want to leave the space tokens there we can put them back after checking what's next).

Comment: I mean that you used `\afterassignment` instead of answering "What am I doing wrong when implementing `\FutureLetNoSpace` [as defined in TEX in Practice]." Not to imply that your answer is not good--it is arguably more elegant.

Comment: Oh, true, I didn't read your question, just the title.

Answer (score 1):

While this problem is older and solved, I wanted to see if I could get my `tokcycle` package to perform this function.  I employed my recently introduced package functionality of popping, pushing, and peeking (futureletting) information from and to the input stream.  I even used it to push the cycle-ending `\endtokcycraw` onto the input stream, which allowed for an undelimited-argument approach required of `\futurelet`.

In the MWE, I `\let` at one point an active-`Q` to be `\mytest`, so that I can easily introduce space tokens following `\mytest`, yet before the tokens we want futureletted.  In the MWE, the input stream is allowed to execute and then, at the end of the line, I show in parens, the token that was peeked at with `\futureletignorespaces`.

The logic is as follows, `\futureletignorespaces`, when invoked, absorbs one argument (`#1`), the token into which the `\futurelet` is to be placed.  It then starts the token cycle (looking eventually for an `\endtokcycraw` to close out the cycle). It absorbs the next token in the input stream into the cycle, which is the token to be executed upon completion of the futurelet.  If this absorbed token is cat-0, it will be passed to the `\Macrodirective` as "`#1`" (or in this case, as `####1`).  If the absorbed token is a character, it is passed to `\Characterdirective`.  In either case, I want to perform the same actions, which are characterized in my definition of `\mydirective`.

It absorbs white space and places the result of that into `\spacesbsorbed`.  It then performs the `\futurelet` by way of `\tcpeek#1` (where `#1` was the argument passed to `\futureletignorespaces`, the specified destination for the futurelet).  It then makes this token-let global.

Now, it starts reassembling the input stream in LIFO fashion:  It pushes back any white space that was earlier absorbed.  It then pushes back the `####1`, which is the token to be executed at the conclusion of the process.  Finally, it pushes `\endtokcycraw` onto the input stream, so that when it is absorbed in the very next iteration of the token cycle, it will terminate the cycle.  The use of the leading `\empty` in two of those pushes is because `\tcpush` is expecting to push something that was earlier popped into a macro (requiring one expansion to recover the replacement text), whereas I want it to push literal tokens.  Thus, the `\empty` gets expanded, leaving the desired literal token to be pushed.

Having defined the cycle directives thus, the token cycle is unleashed with `\tokencyclexpress`, which takes no directive-arguments, instead using predefined directives, which I described above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\futureletignorespaces[1]{%
 \def\mydirective{%
  \tcpopwhitespace\spaceabsorbed
  \tcpeek#1%
  \global\let#1#1%
  \tcpush\spaceabsorbed
  \tcpush{\empty####1}%
  \tcpush{\empty\endtokcycraw}}%
 \expandafter\Characterdirective\expandafter{\mydirective}%
 \expandafter\Macrodirective\expandafter{\mydirective}%
 \tokencyclexpress
}
\def\mytest{\ifx*\nexttok\expandafter\mytestSTAR
  \else\expandafter\mytestNOSTAR\fi}
\def\mytestSTAR#1#2{STAR VERSION, ARGUMENT ``#2''}
\def\mytestNOSTAR#1{NOSTAR VERSION, ARGUMENT ``#1''}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\Q=\active
\letQ\mytest
\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q {xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q*{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q *{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Xy (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok X y (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Xxy (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok X xy (\nexttok)
\end{document}
```

[image]

For a direct comparison, this is the output if `\futureletignorespaces` is replaced with `\futurelet` in the document.  The even-numbered lines differ, because the `\futurelet` sees the space, not the token following the space.

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

Since the question is tagged `tex-core`, I can show that the `tokcycle` approach works in plain tex as well:

```
\input tokcycle
\def\futureletignorespaces#1{%
 \def\mydirective{%
  \tcpopwhitespace\spaceabsorbed
  \tcpeek#1%
  \global\let#1#1%
  \tcpush\spaceabsorbed
  \tcpush{\empty####1}%
  \tcpush{\empty\endtokcycraw}}%
 \expandafter\Characterdirective\expandafter{\mydirective}%
 \expandafter\Macrodirective\expandafter{\mydirective}%
 \tokencyclexpress
}
\def\mytest{\ifx*\nexttok\expandafter\mytestSTAR
  \else\expandafter\mytestNOSTAR\fi}
\def\mytestSTAR#1#2{STAR VERSION, ARGUMENT ``#2''}
\def\mytestNOSTAR#1{NOSTAR VERSION, ARGUMENT ``#1''}

\catcode`\Q=\active
\letQ\mytest
\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\string{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q {xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\string{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q*{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\string{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Q *{xyz} (\ifx\bgroup\nexttok\string{\else\nexttok\fi)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Xy (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok X y (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok Xxy (\nexttok)

\futureletignorespaces\nexttok X xy (\nexttok)
\bye
```

Comment: I like multiple approaches! Thanks for exploring this possibility.