# Add a space after itemize only if no text follows

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, lists, enumerate, itemize

I will start with an example of what I would like to do.

```tex
Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
And the text continues in the same paragraph.

Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}

And the text continues, but in a new paragraph.
```

The code above should produce the following output (notice the spacing between the lines at the end of the `itemize`).

[image]

In some situations, I want to insert an enumeration (itemize or enumerate) *inside* a paragraph, and sometimes I want to insert it in the end and start a new paragraph after it, leaving an empty space. What I call a "paragraph" is not something starting with `\paragraph{title}` but simply a block of text delimited by empty lines in the code, which produces also a block of text delimited by two empty spaces in the output.

The mental image I have is that an enumeration is a part of my paragraph and I want it to behave the same way as anything else I put inside of my paragraph. So if it's the last thing in it, there should be a space after, and if not, then there should be no space. (Also, I put no space *before* my enumeration.)

I know how to always put a space after an enumeration or to never put anything after. But I don't know how to adapt the behaviour in the same way as when a paragraph ends. The way I do it now is to put no space by default and to add some `\vspace{\parskip}` if I end a paragraph with an enumeration.

How can I achieve what I described?

### Complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[1]{
  label=(\arabic*),
  % What do I do here to insert a space if there is a
  % new paragraph
  % after=\vspace{\parskip},
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\section{Non-working example (no space)}
Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
And the text continues in the same paragraph.

Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}

And the text continues, but in a new paragraph.

\section{Desired output (manual space)}
Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
And the text continues in the same paragraph.

Here is some enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item.
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{\parskip}

And the text continues, but in a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

[image: Non-working example and manual correction]

Comment: Using `enumitem` you can add `after=\vspace{\parskip}` just to the list that ends the paragraph. This isn't automatic though.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, thank you! I was aware of this possibility though, this is what I meant by "I know how to always put a space after an enumeration". Thanks for the tagging also.

Comment: @Dabouliplop Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @mforbes Unfortunately no, I just add spacing each time I need it.

Comment: @mforbes Can somebody add a minimal example? By default in the standard classes, there is no additional *vertical* space at the end of a paragraph, so simply removing the additional space after these lists in all cases would satisfy the desiderata. Since that solution doesn't apparently satisfy them and since output you describe as showing a new paragraph doesn't show one with standard formatting, I assume you're using a non-standard class and/or non-standard settings. It's hard to recommend anything since you provide no information about this.

Comment: @cfr I added a mwe using `enumitem`.  Slightly different than the OP's example, but hopefully clear.  *(The example is a little contrived and does not look ideal with short snipits of text... but should give the idea.)*

Comment: Essentially what is being asked for is that you want the effects of the `parskip` package but only after lists, not anywhere else?

Comment: @AlanMunn Which is different from the original question, which wanted space between all paragraphs, but not after lists unless followed by a paragraph break? So we have two questions?

Comment: @mforbes Really, you should ask a new question as you want something different from the OP, if I've understood correctly.

Comment: @cfr I think both the OP and I are asking how to customize lists so that there is less space if the following text is part of the same paragraph, and more space if there is a new paragraph.  I can try to craft a better MWE that matches the OP's output if that is confusing or ask a new question if the OP thinks my MWE does not answer the original question.

Comment: @AlanMunn I added `parskip` to the MWE and think what the OP wants and what I want are the same: extra space when the list is followed by a new paragraph.  Sorry for confusing matters with my MWE that had different formatting.

Comment: @Dabouliplop If what my example demonstrates is somehow orthogonal to what you are asking, please let me know and I will open a new question.

Comment: @mforbes That's what I wanted to ask for, yes. I forgot that I was using the parskip package, I should have added that information. Thank you a lot to have brought attention to this question! I was not hoping for anything anymore but Willie solved it for me. However, I don't understand what is being said in the comments under Willie's answer, and how what you asked for is different from what I asked for...

Comment: (I mean I understand the comments except the part that says that your question is not solved.)

Comment: @Dabouliplop Your case is solved because the extra spaces is already provided by `\parskip` which just needs to be suppressed.  My case does not use `\parskip` and so I still need a way to add the extra space.  See the questions I linked below the answer.

Comment: @mforbes Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parskip}{10ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newenvironment{enumerateD}{\begin{enumerate}[topsep=-\parskip]}
{\end{enumerate}\leavevmode\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
Test
\begin{enumerateD}
        \item Item
        \item Item 2
\end{enumerateD}
test\\
test

Test
\begin{enumerateD}
        \item Item
        \item Item2
\end{enumerateD}

Test
\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

1. We are almost forced into loading `enumitem`, since we cannot easily change `\topsep` otherwise.
2. First we set `\topsep` to *negative* of the `\parskip`; by default the lists leave a vertical space of `\topsep + \parskip` (and also `\partopsep` if your list starts a new paragraph) at the beginning and end of the list. So we set `\topsep` to cancel out that defaul `\parskip`.
3. You don't want to use the `\after` code from `enumitem`, since this is executed *before* ending the list environment, which is too early. We want to throw something in right *after* ending the list environment.
4. Next, we want to detect a blank line that follows. What is useful here is that the list environment ends a paragraph with `\par` and ends up in vertical mode. Usually whether you put in a blank line has zero impact because `\par` is ignored in vertical mode. So what we will do is to force ourselves back in horizontal mode with `\leavevmode`. But once we are in horizontal mode, spaces are starting to be seen, so to avoid spurious spaces at the beginning of the line it is useful to also instruct `\ignorespacesafterend`.
5. The setting of `\parskip` to `10ex` is just to make the effect more pronounced. Setting `\parindent` to `0pt` is to mimic the desired output of shown by the OP where paragraphs are unindented.

---

mforbes asked [in a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571975/add-a-space-after-itemize-only-if-no-text-follows/696854?noredirect=1#comment1730984_571975) for a solution when `\parskip` is not used. The following is one attempt at it.

It turns out that to test for characters automatically after the end of an environment is a bit difficult. This is because in `latex.ltx` you see that when you issue `\end{envname}` what happens at the end is

```
    ...
    \UseHook{env/envname/after}    %% This is when the \AfterEndEnvironment hooks are run
    \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi  %% Mechanism for \ignorespacesafterend
}
```

Because of the `\if@ignore...\fi` it is not feasible to use any code in the After Environment Hook to detect subsequent `\par`s. This leads to our first observation:

> To do what we want we have to modify the `\end{envname}` mechanism itself.

Next, I assume you would want `\end{itemize}<space><newline><newline>` and `\end{itemize}<newline><newline>` to behave the same. In other words, you would want to allow there to be spaces before the `\par` and still detect the `\par`; conversely, I also assume that in a situation where you don't want to ignore spaces, you wouldn't want this behavior either. So

> Need to allow spaces to be gobbled. For this we refer to [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432246/119). A side effect is that you have to issue `\AtEndEnvironment{<envname>}{\ignorespacesafterend}` to activate this mechanism.

More about the implementation:

- We define a new Boolean `\@envendextrapar`; the code detects (after gobbling spaces) whether the next token is `\par`. If so, it sets this boolean to be true, and otherwise do nothing.
- It is the user's responsibility to put code into `\AfterEndEnvironment{<envname>}{...}` using this boolean environment. For the example code below, if the `\par` is detected, an extra `2cm` of space is added.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/432246/119
%%% A version of \futurelet that gobbles spaces
\def\futureletignorespaces#1#2{\def\nextaction{#2}%
  \def\checkspace{\ifx\nexttoken\@sptoken
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\afterassignment\futureletagain\let\nexttoken= }
   {\futurelet#1\nextaction}}%
  \futurelet\nexttoken\checkspace}
\def\futureletagain{\futurelet\nexttoken\checkspace}


\newif\if@envendextrapar
\@envendextraparfalse
\def\doEnvEnd#1{%
        \ifx\@envendextrapartest\par\relax\@envendextrapartrue\fi%
        \UseHook{env/#1/after}%
        \@envendextraparfalse%
        \if@ignore\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi
}
\@namedef{end }#1{%
  \romannumeral
    \IfHookEmptyTF{env/#1/end}%
        {\expandafter\z@}%
        {\z@\UseHook{env/#1/end}}%
    \csname end#1\endcsname\@checkend{#1}%
    \expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
    \if@ignore\def\@tempa{\doEnvEnd{#1}}%
            \def\@tempb{\futureletignorespaces\@envendextrapartest\@tempa}%
    \else\def\@tempb{\UseHook{env/#1/after}}\fi%
    \@tempb
}
\AtEndEnvironment{itemize}{\ignorespacesafterend}  %% Required, see explanation
\AfterEndEnvironment{itemize}{\if@envendextrapar \vspace{2cm}\fi}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

Test
\begin{itemize}
        \item First item
        \item Second item
\end{itemize}
Test again, no blank line.

Test start
\begin{itemize}
        \item Third item
        \item Fourth item
\end{itemize}

Test again, with blank line

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks good to me! In my example, I can just add `\AfterEndEnvironment{enumerate}{\leavevmode\ignorespacesafterend}
` from the `etoolbox` package and it seems to work well.  Let's see if that answers the OP.

Comment: @mforbes I don't think you need `etoolbox` any longer. But I can't get an example working to produce the output I thought you wanted - only the output the OP wanted. But maybe I misunderstood what you wanted.

Comment: @cfr I think you are right about both points. I thought I could use this, but I need to explore how parskip works more. I will ask a new question with a more complete example, but Willie provides a good hint about needing to insert things after the environment.

Comment: @mforbes No problem. Absolutely agree this is useful and you could link to this question from your new one to help people who might try to answer. The `\leavevmode` seemed especially useful. I was already experimenting with hooks - not `\AfterEndEnvironment`: instead `env/enumerate/end`, `env/enumerate/after` and the corresponding paragraph hooks LaTeX now provides. But I can't get something to apply *only* to the paragraph you want ....

Comment: @cfr Will do.  Probably won't get to this until tomorrow.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like my question has been asked and has a partial answer: [Is it possible to have `\partopsep` added below a list environment that is followed by a new paragraph?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476728/is-it-possible-to-have-partopsep-added-below-a-list-environment-that-is-follo)  I need to investigate that first to see if my use case has anything new.

Comment: Also relevant is the [question about `\bottomsep`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-parsep-what-do-they-each-mean-and-what-about/300512#300512), which does not exist, but would probably help.

Comment: @mforbes: see edit, which I think should give you some idea of what you can do.

Comment: Just by way of explanation: my second attempt above (for addressing @mforbes) is based on trying to detect a trailing `\par` after the environment; the solution mentioned in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571975/add-a-space-after-itemize-only-if-no-text-follows/696854#comment1730974_696854) is based on having the next `\par` executed detect whether it is immediately after the end of the environment.

Comment: And for the reasons [explained here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25187/119), it is likely that the `\par` approach is better.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I was just starting to play around with setting a flag at the end of the environment and then detecting this in `\par`.  Those links really help.

Comment: I still need a bit of work to get everything working with `enumitem`, but I think this will get me there.  Thanks for the hints.  I have awarded the bounty.